# OpenCV - camera resolution

Tags: opencv

working on face tracking system and have problem with OpenCV.

If I instantiate the Capture and call QueryFrame() i get 640x480 image resolution. Everything is silky smooth.

```
_grabber = new Capture();
_grabber.QueryFrame();
```

However, if i try to increase the resolution lets say to 800x600 the fps decreases drastically.

```
_grabber = new Capture();
_grabber.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, LiveFeedSize.Height);
_grabber.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, LiveFeedSize.Width);
_grabber.QueryFrame();
```

I am setting the width/height before every QueryFrame().

Anyone with ideas how to increase the frames per seconds? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are instantiating a new Capture for every frame. The correct way to display frames is to instantiate it once and then in a while-loop or for-loop, query the frames. The capture properties only need to be set once as well

Comment: You could try setting the frame rate of the camera through CV_CAP_PROP_FPS. Nonetheless, to preserve bandwidth cameras do stream at lower speed as you increase resolution.

Comment: Hi Erik, I am instantiating it only on start - I just setting the width/height before every QueryFrame() - if I set the width/height on start the values are not preserved

Hi Drodbar, so it could be that the FPS setting is broken when changing the width/height?

Comment: Nope. I mean that your camera sensor, may not be able to transmit as fast as you want. It depends on many factors: physical interface, connection protocol, camera sensor capabilities... You can think that a camera sensor preserves the inequality fps*Resolution <= Constant, so if you increase Resolution, you need dropping your resolution.

Comment: what language is that even ?

Comment: Hi, the camera model is http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/webcam-c930e-business so if i run it under skype on full hd, everything works without problem. Its c#

Answer (score 0):

so after long night I find the solution to the problem. The camera itself is able to work with full resolution, however, the problem was in this line of code

```
MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = _gray.DetectHaarCascade(_face, 1.2, 10, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(150, 150));
```

where the last size parameter was small (27*27) so it takes significant amount of time to calculate. The solution was to increase the value to 150 which is basically minimal face detected size